# How to commit and rollback transaction in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions

I have a huge script for creating tables and porting data from one server. So this sceipt basically has -

1. Create statements for tables.
2. Insert for porting the data to these newly created tables.
3. Create statements for stored procedures.

So I have this code but it does not work basically @@ERROR is always zero I think..

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
--CREATES
--INSERTS
--STORED PROCEDURES CREATES
    -- ON ERROR ROLLBACK ELSE COMMIT THE TRANSACTION
    IF @@ERROR != 0
        BEGIN

            PRINT @@ERROR
                      PRINT 'ERROR IN SCRIPT'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'COMMITTED SUCCESSFULLY'
    END
    GO
```

Can anyone help me write a transaction which will basically rollback on error and commit if everything is fine..Can I use [RaiseError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) somehow here..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't use `@@ERROR`, use `BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH` instead. See this article: [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for a sample procedure:

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
        return;
    end catch   
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx

@@ERROR: Returns the error number for the last Transact-SQL statement executed.

You will have to check after each statement in order to perform the rollback and return.

Commit can be at the end.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Avoid direct references to '@@ERROR'.
It's a flighty little thing that can be lost.

```
Declare @ErrorCode int;
... perform stuff ...
Set @ErrorCode = @@ERROR;
... other stuff ...
if @ErrorCode ......
```