# How to get last updated record values in sql?

Tags: sql

How can I get the last updated record values (the previous values) after a record update?

Comment: You're not even going to tell us what RDBMs you're using?

Comment: Do you mean to say, you want to undo your updates so that the row will have its original values (ie the values it had right before the update)? If so, see Freelancer's answer. Use transactions and roll the transaction back if you want to undo any of your changes to the database.

Comment: I don't want to undo my updates. Just i want the previous values after updation..

Comment: +1 for @scottb's comment. Tell us the RDBMS and we'll be able to help you better. SQL Server has the so-called 'magic tables' for example...

Comment: @noonand These so-called magic tables hold the recently inserted or deleted values of rows... not the previous values of an updated row.

Comment: @TT not IME. AFAIK (and I just don't have the time to verify this right now) they function as follows:  - Whenever you INSERT a record on a table, that record will be there on INSERTED magic table.  
- Whenever you update the record on a table, the existing record will be there on the DELETED magic table and modified new data will be in the INSERTED magic table.  
- Whenever you delete the record on a table, the deleted record will be there on the DELETED magic table only.

Comment: Also note that I said "for example" as we *still* don't know what RDBMS the OP is talking about

Answer (score 1):

You need to use transaction over here.

Before update query, `Begin Transaction`.

When you want to retrieve last record after update, fire `Rollback`.

When you get sure about updation, fire `commit` command.

Can Reger Following:

[How to commit and rollback transaction in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935900/how-to-commit-and-rollback-transaction-in-sql-server)

Comment: I am not using Transactions concept. I am updating table data from one stored procedure and  i want the updated value in some other stored procedure... Execution flow will be like this:
1. Update Stored Procedure
2. Another Stored Procedure
will execute.

Comment: but whatever implementation you are telling me, you need to use transactions in this. and you can use transactions with stored procedures also.

Comment: Do you have IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY and TIMESTAMP column in your table ?

Comment: @Downvoter: care to comment?

Comment: Using transactions and rolling back the transaction, would undo any updates to the row itself. The OP is asking how he can retrieve the previous version of the row, not how to undo the changes to the row. This is simply not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: This is the option, before commiting all the updated transactions he can view the records, which is good for him performance wise

Comment: The OP in the comment section is clearly stating: "I don't want to undo my updates. Just i want the previous values after updation..". Using transactions does not provide an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Right before you update the row, save the row to another table so that you can retrieve the previous row values. This would be called a **log** table if you maintain all previous versions of rows, or a **backup** table if you only want to maintain the last version of rows.

Comment: will it not increse overhead of database?

Comment: @Freelancer It surely will increase overhead, but AFAICT it is the only way to retrieve the previous version of rows (or previous versions in case of log)

Comment: of course this is the option, but performance wise i doubt it. Let it be. Also mention in your anwer how to take backup of table before updation

Comment: @Freelancer Please provide the OP with an alternative that does exactly what he wants. You will find that SQL and in specific SQL Server do not offer such functionality. The OP will have to construct a logging table or backup table for each of the tables where he would want the previous version(s) of rows.

Comment: Transactions are supported almost by all sql servers.

Comment: @Freelancer That is true, but that is irrelevant to this question. The OP is not asking to undo his changes, and thus does not need transactions. He wants a way to retrieve the previous version of rows, and that can be done by constructing a log or backup table and saving the row there before updating it.

Comment: This is the right answer... I don't see why anyone would down-vote this (other than "strategic" reasons).