# Deadlock in online hour system

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-deadlocks

I'm developing an online hour system for one online game. The problem is that sometimes the SQL throws an deadlock error:

`40001 Transaction (Process ID 411) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

The game has 5 rooms and each room is an application with their own SQL connection. The player cannot login in multiple rooms. Each application loops on online players every 10 minutes, sending the command to the SQL procedure to update their online minutes...

`EXEC StoredProcedure 'PlayerName', 7`

Follow the Stored Procedure code:

```
USE [DataBase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure]
    @PlayerName varchar(10),
    @Minutes int
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @PlayerLogin varchar(10),
        @OnlineMinutes int

    SELECT @PlayerLogin = PlayerLogin FROM [dbo].[PlayerTable] WHERE PlayerName = @PlayerName

    UPDATE [dbo].[PlayerTable] SET OnlineMinutes = OnlineMinutes + @Minutes WHERE PlayerName = @PlayerName
    UPDATE [dbo].[AccountTable] SET OnlineMinutes = OnlineMinutes + @Minutes WHERE PlayerLogin = @PlayerLogin

    SELECT @OnlineMinutes = OnlineMinutes FROM [dbo].[AccountTable] WHERE PlayerLogin = @PlayerLogin

    IF ( @OnlineMinutes >= 60 )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[AccountTable] SET OnlineHours = OnlineHours + ( @OnlineMinutes / 60 ), OnlineMinutes = ( @OnlineMinutes % 60 ) WHERE PlayerLogin = @PlayerLogin
    END
END
```

The reason to store the online minutes in both table is because `PlayerTable` is used for ranking page and in the `AccountTable` the online hours it's used as an virtual cash to the player spend in the online hours game store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes.

1) In your calling application, you keep track of @PLayerName and pass it to this procedure. You then use this to look up @PlayerLogin. You should also keep track of @PlayerName in the caller and pass both variables to this procedure, avoiding the lookup of @PlayerLogin inside the proc

2)Replace

```
SELECT @OnlineMinutes = OnlineMinutes FROM [dbo].[AccountTable] WHERE PlayerLogin = @PlayerLogin

IF ( @OnlineMinutes >= 60 )
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[AccountTable] SET OnlineHours = OnlineHours + ( @OnlineMinutes / 60 ),   
        OnlineMinutes = ( @OnlineMinutes % 60 ) WHERE PlayerLogin = @PlayerLogin
END
```

with

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AccountTable] SET 
    OnlineHours = OnlineHours + ( @OnlineMinutes / 60 ) 
 , OnlineMinutes = ( @OnlineMinutes % 60 )
WHERE PlayerLogin = @PlayerLogin AND OnlineMinutes >= 60
```

With these changes you eliminate the SELECT then UPDATE pattern on these 2 tables. This is a good thing for deadlock avoidance.

Finally, you should follow the advice of re-running the transaction. Put all three update statements inside a loop wrapped in a transaction, on error, rollback and let it try the transaction again, of course on success, you simply commit and exit the loop. You still need to make the first 2 changes as avoiding deadlocks is much better than retrying after the deadlock.

You need to place a reasonably small upper bound on the number of retry attempts (I would suggest no more than 5).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain how to do this loop in the transaction?

Comment: You do the transaction in a loop, not the look in the transaction. Many places show how to do transactions, here is a good S/O example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935900/how-to-commit-and-rollback-transaction-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest that use `WITH(ROWLOCK)` Option:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PlayerTable] WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET OnlineMinutes = OnlineMinutes + @Minutes 
WHERE PlayerName = @PlayerName
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain why is that? I need to use just in the `PlayerTable`?

Comment: When you don't use this option, maybe SQL Server lock single page, extra page(8 page) or hole of table, and other process lock to this update.

Comment: Right, so this option is always recommended for an multi SQL connection application that update user data?

Comment: No. This option recommended when you sure that your update command, Update only single row or your table.

Comment: Okay, thanks. In my mind the deadlock only occurs when happens cross resource locks. So this option may fix my problem?